# Extracting the hours from the date "2019-06-29T 1: 25: 40,000 + 00: 00" and counting this as `1h 25 min 40 sec`

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is it possible to extract from this date `var e = new Date ("2019-06-29T 1: 25: 40,000 + 00: 00")` hours and count it as `1h 25 min 40 sec`?

```
var d = new Date("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00");
//hour --> 21:25:38

var e = new Date("2019-06-29T 1:25:40.000+00:00");
//hour --> 1:25:40
```

I want '1: 25: 40' to count as 1h 25 min 40 seconds

1h ---> 3600 seconds

25 min --> 1500 seconds

40 seconds

```
var k = '1: 25: 40';
```

var d = new Date("2019-06-29 21:25:38+00");
d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 5140);

Result: 21:25:38 + 1: 25: 40 = 22:51:18

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide valid input format for Date Object
 such as :
`var date = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');`
// Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT...

Then use it like this:

```
console.log(`${date.getHours()}h:${date.getMinutes()}m:${date.getSeconds()}s `);
```

Comment: `let seconds = ${date.getHours()}h:${date.getMinutes()}m:${date.getSeconds()}s `Could you count the result from  variable  `seconds` to seconds?

Comment: let seconds = date.getHours()*60*60 + date.getMinutes() *60 + date.getSeconds()

Comment: please accept the answer and If you have another question, comment please